# How can I disable IP verification?

Tags: administration, authentication

I am travelling a lot between end-users, and each time my IP changes SalesForce is asking me to authenticate and a code is sent to my mail.

Is there some way I can disable it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From profile level if you added the IP range like below then your issue will resolve.

```
Start Range: 0.0.0.0
End Range: 255.255.255.255
```